# play framework nested html files

Tags: java, nested, playframework-2.2

I have a template index.scala.html

```
@main("Homepage") {
    @if(session().get("login") == null){
        **???**
    }else{
        Logged in as @session().get("login")
    }
}
```

and I would like to load another template generated with static method loginForm() from class Login instead of **???**. *How do I do this?* I've been seeking around for a long time, tried things like

```
@routes.Login.loginForm()
```

or

```
@controllers.Login.loginForm()
```

but neither is working.

I'm working with Play!Framework 2.2.3 **JAVA**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but I wouldn't recommend that you use this type of logic in your templates. It more suited to be put in a controller method that will do the check `if(session().get("login") == null)` then load the appropriate template if it's true and otherwise load your `index.scala.html` with any parameters you had before.

If you're adamant about doing it this way then assuming that your `loginForm` template has no parameters, is called `loginForm.scala.html` and is in the same folder as `index.scala.html` then you have the ability to call templates within others:

```
@main("Homepage") {
    @if(session().get("login") == null){
       @loginForm()
    }else{
        Logged in as @session().get("login")
    }
}
```

This will render any html in that template as well as any logic you may have placed in there whenever `index.scala.html` is rendered.

For more information: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaTemplateUseCases